# Unsupported query while retrieving list of users via Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

**I want to retrieve list of specific users** who were created before some particular date via Microsoft Graph Explorer.

I am following this Microsoft document : [List users - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to form the query.

I tried querying like below:

```
GET
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=createdDateTime, displayName, id, mail&$filter=createdDateTime le 2021-07-14
```

**But I am getting the error as below:**

```json
{
"error": {
"code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
"message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'createdDateTime' of resource 'User'.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2022-05-12T14:24:38",
"request-id": "5378dd7c-7413-4b97-9399-09a6f4f11c50",
"client-request-id": "ba9f70f4-f33c-c753-fb3a-c6f1a197ef46"
}}}
```

I have given the **required permissions** mentioned in the Microsoft document. I am thinking that there is something wrong in my query.

**Can anyone help me with the query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind getting the error is, **you are filtering only with Date.**

To resolve the error, you have to **include time** along with date like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=createdDateTime, displayName, id, mail&$filter=createdDateTime le 2021-04-06T08:03:07Z&$count=true
```

**I have tried in my environment** and got the list of users successfully with the above query:

[image]

Make sure to include **Time stamp** in below format:

**`createdDateTime ge yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`**

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Azure graph API for users doesn't support filter by createdDateTime anymore - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/499031/azure-graph-api-for-users-doesn39t-support-filter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please change your query to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=createdDateTime, displayName, id, mail&$filter=createdDateTime le 2021-07-14T00:00:00Z
```

and then you should not get this error.

Basically you will need to specify the date/time value in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` format.